# @link to another package inside of a package-info.java

Tags: java, javadoc

Is there any way to link from an package-info.java to another package outside of this package (in the same Project)?

If I try to do this in java 7 I always get:

```
warning - Tag @link: reference not found:
```

Comment: Did you find out how to do this yet? (and: you *do* want to reference another package, not someting inside the package, right?)

Answer (score 11):

Both `@link` and `@see` [support linking to packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#see).

I have the following code in one of my `package-info.java` files and the javadoc tool generates the link:

```
/**
 * <p>Note, however, that the classes in {@link gov.va.med.srcalc.domain}
 * define the vast majority of the data mapping via JPA annotations.</p>
 */
package gov.va.med.srcalc.db;
```

We use Gradle as our build tool and I have found, however, that Gradle does not generate the link and produces a `reference not found: gov.va.med.srcalc.domain` warning. Maybe it's a bug in Gradle.

Answer (score 6):

A plain link with a `@docroot` works for the standard Java doclet:

```
/**
 * See the 
 * <a href="{@docRoot}/com/mycorp/package-summary.html#package_description">
 *    package overview
 * </a> for more information.
 */
```

It does not matter whether you need this in package-info.java or in a class, the `{@link}` tag cannot handle links to packages.

Comment: This might work when you actually generate documentation but doesn't work with dynamic pop-up docs in Eclipse. Eclipse does support the {@link com.mypackage} form of link.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround, but at least if you link to some file in the package `com.foo.Bar` Eclipse will allow you to navigate from `Bar` into the `package-info.java` description by hovering over/clicking on `foo` afterwards in Inline Previews etc.

Answer (score 0):

Half the answer is that `{@link some.package.name}` indeed links to the package.

The other half of the answer, as I just figured out by luck, is that `javadoc` must be called with package names on the command line. Well, this is a guess, because I am actually using ant's `<javadoc/>` task, but as soon as I add a `<packageset/>`, the `reference not found` warnings disappeared and the links where available in the generated javadoc.

Answer (score -3):

you have to import the used Package so javadoc knows the the namespace you are refering to.

package-info.java should look link this:

```
import package.subpackage.ClassnameYouWantToLink;
/**
* {@link ClassnameYouWantToLink}
*/
```

if you don't want to import the package you need the full quallified package-Name infront of the ClassName:

```
/**
* {@link package.subpackage.ClassnameYouWantToLink}
*/
```

Comment: I think the op wants to link to the package, not an object inside the package.

Comment: A package is a folder and cannot contain a Java-doc itself (and you are only able to link to files). So as a convention you add a `package-info` class in the package and link to this class.

Comment: You cannot use an import in package-info.java for this purpose. The import comes after the package and the javadoc is on the package element, so the import is after the javadoc and the javadoc compiler does not see it.